# How do you do to do the same but for many parameters, like for example name, lastname, date of birth, etc (only class parameters) in apache isis?

Tags: apache, isis

I´m trying to get the default values of a class so as to update that class. I achieved it for one single parameter, but I couldn´t do so for more than one parameter at the same time. What do I have to do in that case?

Example with single attribute:

```
@action(...)
public Modelo UpdateNombre(

    @Parameter(...)
    @ParameterLayout(...)
    final String nombre){

    setNombre(nombre);
    return this;

}

public String defaul0UpdateNombre() {return getNombre();}
```

Example with multiple attribute:

```
@action(...)
public Modelo UpdateModelo(

    @Parameter(...)
    @ParameterLayout(...)
    final String nombre,

    @Parameter(...)
    @ParameterLayout(...)
    final int cantidad,

    @Parameter(...)
    @ParameterLayout(...)
    final boolean baja){

    setNombre(nombre);
    setCantidad(cantidad);
    setBaja(baja);
    return this;

}

public Modelo defaul0UpdateModelo() {

    Modelo modelo;
    modelo.nombre = getNombre();
    modelo.cantidad = getCantidad();
    modelo.baja = getBaja();

    return modelo;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is default{N}Xxx() were N=0,1,2

Therefore:

```
@Action(...)
public Modelo updateModelo(

    @Parameter(...)
    @ParameterLayout(...)
    final String nombre,

    @Parameter(...)
    @ParameterLayout(...)
    final int cantidad,

    @Parameter(...)
    @ParameterLayout(...)
    final boolean baja){

    setNombre(nombre);
    setCantidad(cantidad);
    setBaja(baja);
    return this;

}

public Modelo default0UpdateModelo() {

    Modelo modelo;
    modelo.nombre = getNombre();
    modelo.cantidad = getCantidad();
    modelo.baja = getBaja();

    return modelo;

}
```